# Create Variant from FILETIME

Tags: c++, variant, opc

I want to create a VARIANT or _variant_t from a FILETIME in c/c++.
Basically, this is what I want:

```cpp
FILETIME ft;  
//Populate ft  
VARIANT vFt;  
VariantInit(&vFt);  
vFt.vt = VT_FILETIME;
```

Now, how do I set ft inside vFt?

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: Are you really doing it twice, or is it a copy/paste error?

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, you can't store a FILETIME in a VARIANT. From the header file:

```
 *  VT_FILETIME               [P]     FILETIME
```

note the [P], and the key above it in the header file:

```
 * * [V] - may appear in a VARIANT
 * * [T] - may appear in a TYPEDESC
 * * [P] - may appear in an OLE property set
 * * [S] - may appear in a Safe Array
```

FILETIME can only appear in an OLE property set - not a variant.

There is a VT_DATE that you might be able to use instead.

### Bonus Reading

[VARENUM enumeration (wtypes.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypes/ne-wtypes-varenum)

The following table shows where these values can be used.

| Value | VARIANT | TYPEDESC | Property set | Safe array |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT_ARRAY | ✔️ |  |  |  |
| VT_BLOB |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_BLOB_OBJECT |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_BOOL | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_BSTR | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_BSTR_BLOB |  |  |  |  |
| VT_BYREF | ✔️ |  |  |  |
| VT_CARRAY |  | ✔️ |  |  |
| VT_CF |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_CLSID |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_CY | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_DATE | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_DECIMAL | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| VT_DISPATCH | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| VT_EMPTY | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_ERROR | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_FILETIME |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_HRESULT |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_I1 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_I2 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_I4 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_I8 |  | ✔️ | ✔️ |  |
| VT_INT | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_INT_PTR |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_LPSTR |  | ✔️ | ✔️ |  |
| VT_LPWSTR |  | ✔️ | ✔️ |  |
| VT_NULL | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_PTR |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_R4 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_R8 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_RECORD | ✔️ |  | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_SAFEARRAY |  | ✔️ |  |  |
| VT_STORAGE |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_STORED_OBJECT |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_STREAM |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_STREAMED_OBJECT |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_UI1 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_UI2 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_UI4 | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_UI8 |  | ✔️ | ✔️ |  |
| VT_UINT | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| VT_UINT_PTR |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_UNKNOWN | ✔️ | ✔️ |  | ✔️ |
| VT_USERDEFINED |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_VARIANT | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| VT_VECTOR |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_VERSIONED_STREAM |  |  | ✔️ |  |
| VT_VOID |  |  | ✔️ |  |

Comment: I need to call an OPC HDA Automation function in C++ (syncReadRaw) which accepts a variant. This variant can either contain a relative time (as a string) or an absolute time (as a FILETIME). I need to send absolute times to this function. Is there any other option for achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, they have not given a working example in C++. They have given one for VB, but using relative times only. So, now, if sending a FILETIME is not going to be possible, then I will have to think of converting an absolute time (like say 30-mar-2012 10:15:23) to a relative one using some math.

Comment: Is it possible that you can pass an OPCHDA_TIME (setting the ftTime member)? I got this from a message board and am wondering if that structure is an OPC extension to a variant...

Comment: Update:  
Was able to solve this by converting the FILETIME to a DATE and constructing a variant from it:

    DATE d = convertFileTimeToDate(ft);
    _variant_t vDate(d);
    //Call opc function passing vDate

Thanks JTeagle.  

Regards, 
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

Use InitVariantFromFileTime

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762323(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

For those still looking you can try Scott's answer. Here's how I did it using the ATLComTime.h library which takes a few more steps.

```
FileTime fileTime = yourFileTime;
// dateFileTime will automatically cast to DATE when used as a parameter
COleDateTime dateFileTime(fileTime);
```

Since DATE is a COM friendly type you can simply give the 'dateFileTime' variable as a method parameter. If you still want to use the VARIANT simply set the 'dateFileTime' variable into a VARIANT.

```
VARIANT varDate;
VariantInit(&varDate);
varDate.vt = VT_DATE;
varDate.date = dateFileTime;
// Use the varDate varaible
// ... call some method or use locally
// Don't forget to clear the VARIANT from memory after use
VariantClear(&varDate);
```

In the called method (still in C++), ie getting the FILETIME back from a DATE variable.
The COleDateTime wants to give you a SYSTEMTIME instead of a FILETIME so we have to jump through a few hoops.

```
FILETIME fileTime;
if (variantDateTime.vt == VT_DATE) // only use if DATE was put into a VARIANT
{
  COleDateTime oleDateTime(variantDateTime.date);
  SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
  oleDateTime.GetAsSystemTime(sysTime);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(&sysTime, &fileTime);
}
```

If you didn't use a VARIANT you can just initialize the COleDateTime type with the DATE variable.

```
COleDateTime oleDateTime(dateVariable);
... // etc as above
```

As stated above it's a bit more work than Scotts answer, but is another way to get a FILETIME across the COM interface barrier.