# How to parameterize 12/30/1899 to SQL Server native client when DataTypeCompatility is on?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, oledb, ado

## Short Version

Trying to pass the `datetime` value **12/30/1899** to SQL Server, fails with **Invalid date format** - but only for the native client drivers, and only in **DataTypeCompatiblity** mode.

## Long Version

When trying to use parameterized queries in ADO, against SQL Server:

```
SELECT ?
```

I parameterize the `datetime` value as an `adDBTimeStamp`:

```
//Language agnostic, vaguely C#-like pseudo-code
void TestIt()
{
   DateTime dt = new DateTime("3/15/2020");
   VARIANT v = DateTimeToVariant(dt);

   Command cmd = new Command();
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ? AS SomeDate";
   cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v);
   
   Connection cn = GetConnection();
   cmd.Set_ActiveConnection(cn);
   cmd.Execute(out recordsAffected, EmptyParam, adExecuteNoRecords);
}
```

And that works fine when the date is `3/15/2020`.

You create a [`VARIANT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/3fe7db9f-5803-4dc4-9d14-5425d3f5461f), with a [`VType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/3fe7db9f-5803-4dc4-9d14-5425d3f5461f) of 7 ([`VT_DATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/35c9bf2d-b8e8-4d7d-a50f-367da0d99fce)), and a value that is an 8-byte floating point value:

```
VARIANT
   Int32  vt = 7; //VT_DATE
   Double date = 0;
```

### But it fails on 12/30/1899

If I do the same test code with one particular datetime, it fails:

```
void TestIt()
{
   DateTime dt = new DateTime("12/30/1899");
   VARIANT v = DateTimeToVariant(dt);

   Command cmd = new Command();
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ? AS SomeDate";
   cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v);
   
   Connection cn = GetConnection();
   cmd.Set_ActiveConnection(cn);
   cmd.Execute(out recordsAffected, EmptyParam, adExecuteNoRecords);
}
```

The ADO OLEDB provider throws an exception (i.e. before it even reaches SQL Server):

```
Invalid date format
```

### But it doesn't happen with all SQL Server OLEDB providers

When debugging this issue, I realized it doesn't happen with all of the SQL Server OLEDB providers. Microsoft generally has 4 OLE DB Providers for SQL Server:

- `SQLOLEDB`: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (has shipped with Windows since Windows 2000)
- `SQLNCLI`: SQL Server Native Client (shipped with SQL Server 2005)
- `SQLNCLI10`: SQL Server Native Client 11.0 (shipped with SQL Server 2008)
- `SQLNCLI11`: SQL Server Native Client 12.0 (shipped with SQL Server 2012)
- `MSOLEDBSQL`: Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (shipped with SQL Server 2016)

When trying it with some different providers, it **does** work fine for some:

- `SQLOLEDB`: Works
- `SQLNCLI11` (without DataTypeCompatibility): Works
- `SQLNCLI11` (with DataTypeCompatiility on): Fails

### DataTypeCompatibility?

Yes. ActiveX Data Objects (ADO), a friendly COM wrapper around the unfriendly COM OLEDB API, doesn't understand the new `date`, `time`, `xml`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset` data types. New OLEDB data type constants were created to represents these new types. So any existing OLEDB applications wouldn't understand the new constants.

To that end, a new [keyword is supported by the *"native"* OLE DB drivers:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

- `DataTypeCompatibility=80`

which you can add to your connection string:

> "Provider=SQLNCLI11; Data Source=screwdriver; User ID=hatguy; Password=hunter2;**DataTypeCompatibility=80;**"

This instructs the OLEDB driver to only return OLEDB data types that were in existance when OLEDB was first invented:

| SQL Server data type | SQLOLEDB | SQLNCLI | SQLNCLI (w/DataTypeCompatibility=80) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Xml | adLongVarWChar | 141 (DBTYPE_XML) | adLongVarChar |
| datetime | adDBTimeStamp | adDBTimeStamp | adDBTimeStamp |
| datetime2 | adVarWChar | adDBTimeStamp | adVarWChar |
| datetimeoffset | adVarWChar | 146 (DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET) | adVarWChar |
| date | adVarWChar | adDBDate | adVarWChar |
| time | adVarWChar | 145 (DBTYPE_DBTIME2) | adVarWChar |
| UDT |  | 132 (DBTYPE_UDT) | adVarBinary (documented,untested) |
| varchar(max) | adLongVarChar | adLongVarChar | adLongVarChar |
| nvarchar(max) | adLongVarWChar | adLongVarWChar | adLongVarWChar |
| varbinary(max) | adLongVarBinary | adLongVarBinary | adLongVarBinary |
| timestamp | adBinary | adBinary | adBinary |

### And there's the failure

When:

- trying to parameterize a `datetime` value
- with a value of `12/30/1899`
- when using a *"native client"* driver
- and `DataTypeCompatilibty` is on
- the driver itself chokes on the value
- when its value is, in fact perfectly fine.

There's nothing inherently wrong with trying to use a date of '12/30/1899`:

- `SELECT CAST('18991230' AS datetime)` works fine
- it works fine in the original OLE DB driver
- it works fine in the *"native"* OLE DB drivers
- it just fails in the native driver with `DataTypeCompatibility` on

Obviously this is a bug in Microsoft OLE DB drivers. But it's an absolute truth that Microsoft will never, *ever*, **ever**, ***EVER***, fix the bug.

### So how to work-around it?

I can detect this special datetime, and I can try to work around this bug in our data access layers.

- But I need a value I can place into a `VARIANT` structure,
- that represents `12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM`
- that works under `SQOLEDB`
- and under `SQLNCLI`xx drivers
- and under `MSOLEDBSQL` driver
- in `DataTypeCompatibilityMode`
- (and what the hell, even with the mode off - although it's invalid to use ADO without it on)

### T-SQL generated by the driver

When the OLE DB driver *does* bother to actually do what i say, we can profile the RPC generated:

**SQOLEDB**

> `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT @P1 AS SomeDate',N'@P1 datetime','1899-12-30 00:00:00'`

**SQLNCLI11**

> `exec sp_executesql N'SELECT @P1 AS SomeDate',N'@P1 datetime2(0)','1899-12-30 00:00:00'`

## CMRE (Delphi)

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  ComObj,
  ActiveX,
  ADOdb,
  ADOint,
  Variants;

function GetConnection(Provider: string; DataTypeCompatibility: Boolean): _Connection;
var
    connectionString: string;
begin
{
    SQLOLEDB - Default provider with Windows
    SQLNCLI11 - SQL Server 2008 native client
}
    connectionString := 'Provider='+Provider+'; Data Source=screwdriver;User ID=hydrogen;Password=hunter2;';
    if DataTypeCompatibility then
        connectionString := connectionString+'DataTypeCompatibility=80';

    Result := CoConnection.Create;
    Result.Open(connectionString, '', '', adConnectUnspecified);
end;

procedure Test(ProviderName: string; DataTypeCompatibility: Boolean);
var
    dt: TDateTime;
    v: OleVariant;
    cmd: _Command;
    cn: _Connection;
    recordsAffected: OleVariant;
    s: string;
begin
    dt := EncodeDate(1899, 12, 30);// 12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM (also known in Delphi as zero)
    v := dt; //the variant is of type VT_DATE (7)

    cmd := CoCommand.Create;
    cmd.CommandText := 'SELECT ? AS SomeDate';
    cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter('', adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v));

    try
        cn := GetConnection(ProviderName, DataTypeCompatibility);
    except
        on E: Exception do
            begin
                WriteLn('Provider '+ProviderName+' not installed: '+E.message);
                Exit;
            end;
    end;

    if SameText(ProviderName, 'SQLOLEDB') then
        s := ''
    else if DataTypeCompatibility then
        s := ' (with DataTypeCompatibility)'
    else
        s := ' (without DataTypeCompatibility)';

    cmd.Set_ActiveConnection(cn);
    try
        cmd.Execute({out}recordsAffected, EmptyParam, adExecuteNoRecords);
        WriteLn('Provider '+ProviderName+s+': success.');
    except
        on E:Exception do
            begin
                WriteLn('Provider '+ProviderName+s+' failed: '+E.Message);
            end;
    end;

end;

procedure Main;
begin
    CoInitialize(nil);

    Test('SQLOLEDB', False);        //SQL Server client that ships with Windows since 2000

    Test('SQLNCLI', False);     //SQL Server 2005 native client
    Test('SQLNCLI', True);      //SQL Server 2005 native client, w/ DataTypeCompatibilty

    Test('SQLNCLI10', False);   //SQL Server 2008 native client
    Test('SQLNCLI10', True);    //SQL Server 2008 native client, w/ DataTypeCompatibilty

    Test('SQLNCLI11', False);   //SQL Server 2012 native client
    Test('SQLNCLI11', True);    //SQL Server 2012 native client, w/ DataTypeCompatibilty

    Test('MSOLEDBSQL', False);  //SQL Server 2016 native client
    Test('MSOLEDBSQL', True);   //SQL Server 2016 native client, w/ DataTypeCompatibilty
end;


begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
    WriteLn('Press enter to close');
    ReadLn;
end.
```

And while this is not a Delphi-specific question; I am using Delphi. So it's tagged as Delphi. If you complain [I'm going to choke your tongue out.](https://youtu.be/wAQdvyRIHco?t=7461)

> **Note**: This is not ADO.net, it is ADO. It is not managed .NET Framework Class Library, it is the native Win32 COM OLE DB API.

Comment: I am aware of the special significange of `December 30, 1899` in OLE automation in general, and [VARIANT record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/35c9bf2d-b8e8-4d7d-a50f-367da0d99fce) in particular. On the other hand, it's simply a C [`VARIANT` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/3fe7db9f-5803-4dc4-9d14-5425d3f5461f) with `VType` of `VT_DATE`, and a floating-point value of zero.

Comment: Why do you need to store that date in the database?

Comment: Set `NumericScale` property of your parameter to anything in 1-7 range to force mapping of your parameter to `datetime2` instead of `smalldatetime`. Your CMRE should give the same results for any date outside 1900-01-01 - 2079-06-06 (SQLOLEDB will also fail if the date is outside datetime range).

Comment: @Oliver There were things that happened on that date. For situations where i want the field to be NULL, i would write null instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrakNicku had the answer.

> Set `NumericScale` property of your parameter to anything in 1-7 range.

Changing the code from:

```
Parameter p = cmd.CreateParameter("", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v);
```

to

```
Parameter p = cmd.CreateParameter("", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v);
p.NumericScale = 1;
```

works.

It even works with SQLOLEDB driver against SQL Server 2000.

### Precision and Scale of different data types

Returning rowsets from SQL Server containing different data types, i can ask OLEDB what the `Precision`, and `NumericScale` of various T-SQL data types are:

```
SQL Server type   ADO type               Precision  NumericScale  DefinedSize
----------------  ---------------------  ---------  ------------  -----------
int               adInteger (3)          10         255           4
real              adSingle (4)           7          255           4
money             adCurrency (6)         19         255           8
bit               adBoolean (11)         255        255           2
tinyint           adUnsignedTinyInt (17) 3          255           1
bigint            adBigInt (20)          19         255           8
uniqueidentifier  adGUID (72)            255        255           16
char(35)          adChar (129)           255        255           35
nchar(35)         adWChar (130)          255        255           35
decimal(15,5)     adNumeric (131)        15         5             19
datetime          adDBTimeStamp (135)    23         3             16
varchar(35)       adVarChar (200)        255        255           35
text              adLongVarChar (201)    255        255           2147483647
varchar(max)      adLongVarChar (201)    255        255           2147483647
nvarchar(35)      adVarWChar (202)       255        255           35
nvarchar(max)     adLongVarWChar (203)   255        255           1073741823
xml               adLongVarWChar (203)   255        255           1073741823
image             adLongVarBinary (205)  255        255           2147483647
varbinary(max)    adLongVarBinary (205)  255        255           2147483647
```

Since SQL Server returns a `datetime` field with a `NumericScale` of **3**; there ***may*** be a virtue in changing:

```
Parameter p = cmd.CreateParameter("", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v);
p.NumericScale = 1;
```

to

```
Parameter p = cmd.CreateParameter("", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 0, v);
p.NumericScale = 3;
```

### Bonus Reading

Don't ever, *ever*, **EVER** try to parameterize a `datetime` as `adDBTimestamp`. There are data-loss bugs in Microsoft's SQL Server OLEDB drivers (all of them):

- <kbd>SQLOLEDB</kbd> (1999) - Fails
- <kbd>SQLNCLI</kbd> (2005) - Fails
- <kbd>SQLNCLI10</kbd> (2008) - Fails
- <kbd>SQLNCLI11</kbd> (2010) - Fails
- <kbd>MSOLEDBSQL</kbd> (2012) - Fails

The [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738080/12597) is to parameterize all `datetime` values as a string (e.g. `adVarChar`) using the *"ODBC 24-hour format"*:

- `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.zzz`
- `2021-03-21 18:16:22.619`