# Assigning 31.12.2099 to an OLE DB parameter of type DBTimeStamp doesnt work after changing to MSOLEDBSQL

Tags: sql-server, oledb, smalldatetime

To use the "OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" I changed the provider in the connection string from `Provider=SQLOLEDB.1` to `Provider=MSOLEDBSQL` as it should be. Now I'm getting the error "Invalid date format" if I assign the date 31.12.2099 to an OLE DB parameter of the type DBTimeStamp:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@ValidFrom", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);`

I found out that OleDbType.DBTimeStamp (DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP) maps to the SQL SERVER data type *smalldatetime*, which has the range from 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06. Indeed if I change it from 31.12.2099 to 06.06.2079, it works without a problem (see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/175510/oledbtype-dbtimestamp-in-oledbdataadapter-error-be.html).

The solution would be to use OleDbType.DBDate instead of OleDbType.DBTimeStamp. **But what if I want to keep the time too?** So my questions are:

1. Why didn't I have this problem before the change of the connection provider? It seems like this range limitation was ignored.
2. Which type should I use now to keep both date and time? There are only three datetime related OLE DB types: DBDate,DBTime and DBTimeStamp.

**Remarks**

Trying to set the scale as described in this link didn't work ([How to parameterize 12/30/1899 to SQL Server native client when DataTypeCompatility is on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60695196/how-to-parameterize-12-30-1899-to-sql-server-native-client-when-datatypecompatil)).

```
var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ValidFrom", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp);
param.Scale = 3;
param.Value = new DateTime(2099, 12, 31);
```

I'm getting in this case the following error:

```
The fractional part of the provided time value overflows the scale of the corresponding SQL Server parameter or column. Increase bScale in DBPARAMBINDINFO or column scale to correct this error.
```

I got this same error, when I changed the connection string as mentioned before. Then I solved it by adding `DataTypeCompatibility=80` to the connection string and it was fine (see also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1241147c-42a1-40a5-b4c6-374374e462cd/the-fractional-part-of-the-provided-time-value-overflows-the-scale-of-the-corresponding-sql-server?forum=transactsql).

Comment: Why not use a [`SqlDbType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your answer. But it's a great effort to change everything to SqlConnection. But anyway do you have any idea, why I didn't have this problem with the old provider?